# Need to encrypt a file I have it all written but error in reading file

Tags: c, encryption, error-handling

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int encrypt_data(FILE *);

int main(void)
{
   FILE *fp;
   int return_code;

   printf("Please enter the file to be encrypted: ");
   char filename[200];
   fgets(filename, 200, stdin);
   fp=fopen("filename","w+");

   return_code = encrypt_data(fp);

   return 0;
}
int encrypt_data(FILE *disk_fp)
{
  int i;
  unsigned long int file_size;
  int key_length;
  char *file_buff = NULL;

  char key[] = "12`3-vk0fn";

  key_length = strlen(key);

  fseek(disk_fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  file_size = ftell(disk_fp);

  rewind(disk_fp);

  file_buff = malloc(file_size);

  if( fread(file_buff, file_size, 1, disk_fp) != 1)
  {
   printf("Error in reading file\n");
   return -1;
  }

  for( i=0; i<file_size; i++)
  {
   file_buff[i] = file_buff[i] ^ key[i%key_length];
  }

  rewind(disk_fp);

  if( fwrite(file_buff, file_size, 1, disk_fp) != 1)
  {
   printf("Error in writing encrypted data to file\n");
   return -1;
  }
  free(file_buff);
  fclose(disk_fp);

return 0;
}
```

The file I am trying to encrypt is "encrypt.txt" it is just a sentence of nonsense but when I compile this code and then ./a.out it asks me for the file name i enter encrypt.txt I thought it might just want the name but either way it returns "Error in reading file".

I think my fgets() fopen() is the culprit but I am very very lost in how to fix it.

If you could find the error in the code and then explain why it was messing things up it would help me in the future. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check the return value of fopen for null.

Comment: Please note that this isn't an effective form of encryption. It's very easy to break by correlation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove double quotes of the filename variable. And put it as

```
fp=fopen(filename,"w+");
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am wrong but with close inspection I thought you better use

```
scanf("%s", filename);
```

Instead of the fgets() function. You are reading text from user and not from file at that moment after all.

Comment: I did change to scanf it does the same thing but I did notice when I enter the file name to be encrypted it will give me the error and then when I look back in the directory it is creating that file name. I checked this by entering a random file name and it puts that file in the current directory.