# Encryption code doesn't write back to file

Tags: c

I compile the code then run it but it returns "Error in writing encrypted data to file. So I assume the issue is somewhere in fwrite.

But I cannot pinpoint it.

I need some help here if you could explain the problem that would be very helpful thanks a lot

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int encrypt_data(FILE *);

    int main(void)
    {
       FILE *fp;
       int return_code;

       printf("Please enter the file to be encrypted: ");
       char filename[200];
       scanf("%s", filename);
       fp=fopen(filename,"r");

       return_code = encrypt_data(fp);

       return 0;
    }
    int encrypt_data(FILE *disk_fp)
    {
      int i;
      unsigned long int file_size;
      int key_length;
      char *file_buff = NULL;

      char key[] = "12`3-vk0fn";

      key_length = strlen(key);

      fseek(disk_fp, 0, SEEK_END);
      file_size = ftell(disk_fp);

      rewind(disk_fp);

      file_buff = malloc(file_size);

      if( fread(file_buff, file_size, 1, disk_fp) != 1)
      {
       printf("Error in reading file\n");
       return -1;
      }

      for( i=0; i<file_size; i++)
      {
       file_buff[i] = file_buff[i] ^ key[i%key_length];
      }

      rewind(disk_fp);

      if( fwrite(file_buff, file_size, 1, disk_fp) != 1)
      {
       printf("Error in writing encrypted data to file\n");
       return -1;
      }
      free(file_buff);
      fclose(disk_fp);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you expect the return value of `fwrite` to be 1?

Comment: Very nearly a duplicate of [Need to encrypt a file I have it all written but error in reading file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365298/need-to-encrypt-a-file-i-have-it-all-written-but-error-in-reading-file).

Comment: If you ever wonder why a system call fails, try letting the system tell you.  Instead of `printf( "my ambiguous error message" )`, try `perror( "fwrite" )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening file with "r" mode which means readonly. Then you try write something to it. By the way you don't check that you open file without errors and don't close it when fwrite/fread failed.

Comment: Thanks a lot to William Pursell and Adrian Krupa...Adrian it was just like you said in read only and William you thought this noob programmer perror() thanks both.